# Can't remove phantom display "None-1-1"

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, arch-linux, xorg, xrandr

I'm using arch with gnome and I've been noticing my mouse disappears when moved to the right. It doesn't just stops at the last pixel it actually "goes off" my screen. In my gnome settings I've found an "Unknown display" of 640x480 resolution, which is weird as I only have one monitor connected through HDMI to my graphics card.

Then I used `xrandr` which returned me this

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
None-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   640x480       60.00 +
```

I've deduced my "Unknown display" is the None-1-1 that is connected as they have the same resolution

Using the arch documentation I tried `xrandr --output None-1-1 --off`. Unforntunately I got :

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  49
  Current serial number in output stream:  51
```

I don't know what to do next. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I ended up installing kde, running the command, no error. Then removing gnome and reinstalling it. It seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Ok no it didn't the issue reappeared

Answer (score 0):

ArchWiki describes how to [disable a phantom monitor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr#Disabling_phantom_monitor) for Xorg.

Modify the Xorg configuration (e.g. using a drop-in configuration file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`) like so:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "None-1-1"
    Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection
```

This will make the system ignore the monitor with the given identifier.